# Specs2 Specification Spring Autowire

Tags: spring, scala, unit-testing, specs2

I would like to use the Specs2 test framework for testing, but I am getting an java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException when I try to integrate it with Spring.

There is a [specs2-spring library](https://github.com/eigengo/specs2-spring), but that is using 2.10 and an old version of specs2. I looked at  [this question about scalaTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282471/how-do-i-integrate-scalatest-with-spring) and it got me to this code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(Array("classpath:applicationContext.xml"))
class TryItTest extends SpecificationWithJUnit{

  @Autowired val db:DriverManagerDataSource = null
  new TestContextManager(this.getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this)

  "this thing should" should{
    "run ok" in {
      db.getConnection
      success
    }
  }
}
```

but when I try to run the test I get:

```
Nov 09, 2015 2:11:31 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
    Nov 09, 2015 2:11:31 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@243d315f: startup date [Mon Nov 09 14:11:31 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    Nov 09, 2015 2:11:31 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
    INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    Nov 09, 2015 2:11:31 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
    SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@131746d9] to prepare test instance [my.package.TryItTest@12474a03]
    java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:284)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:282)
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:116)
```

If I switch from `SpecificationWithJUnit` to `SpecWithJUnit` it runs the test without error, but I do not want to have in include all those traits by hand. I think (at least) one of the traits in  [Matchers](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/matcher/src/main/scala/org/specs2/matcher/Matchers.scala) is causing the problem. Has anyone else tried to do this with Specs2? Am I missing something important?

(I am using Spring V4.1.0.RELEASE)

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I was not using the latest version of scalaz and specs2. Everything works perfectly now.